PayPal JavaSDK: get what card/account was selected when created Payment Method Token
Is there any way to get information about card/bank account was selected by user during approve of Payment Method Token creation via PayPal's REST API?
I see that this information is displayed in 'Automatic Payments' -> 'Payment method' field (can be reached via Settings) and want to have it shown in my application too.

Using com.paypal.sdk.paypal-server-sdk versions 0.5.2
To create Token using POST '/v3/vault/setup-tokens' and then /v3/vault/payment-tokens (to make it not temporal) with 'paypal' populated in 'paymentSource' object (as at this point don't know anything about what card/account user might want to use).
Example of Request DTO for the first endpoint (if it may give some information):
{
  "payment_source": {
    "paypal": {
      "description": "Payment Method Token",
      "permit_multiple_payment_tokens": true,
      "usage_type": "MERCHANT",
      "customer_type": "CONSUMER",
      "experience_context": {
        "locale": "en-US",
        "return_url": "some_url_from_my_application",
        "cancel_url": "some_another_url_from_my_application",
        "shipping_preference": "NO_SHIPPING",
        "vault_instruction": "ON_PAYER_APPROVAL"
      }
    }
  }
}

Tried to get it via GET '/v3/vault/payment-tokens/{id}' (as ResponseDTO looks like it can return such data), but no luck. Only 'paymentSource.paypal' was populated (with data provided when token was created with some Ids set).

There is a difference between creating a payment token that is payment_source.paypal and one that is something else such as payment_source.card
In the case of paypal, the token is not associated with a specific funding source (other than what they selected as a default if no balance) and so the correct thing to display as what's tokenized is the PayPal account itself, perhaps using an email that is returned
